# Computing a p-value of a 2-sided Chi-squared test for one variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, p-value, chi-squared-test

Below is a simple question from a textbook. I answer the question by computing the critical values for a critical region $\alpha = 0.05$ for a Chi-squared distribution (42.95, 86.83) and then commenting that the chi-squared value (63.75) is within the interval. However, the book gives a p-value and I don't know how this is calculated.

> Aflotoxins produced by mold on peanut crops in Virginia must be
> monitored. A sample of 64 batches of peanuts reveals levels of 24.17
> ppm, on average, with a variance of 4.25 ppm. Test the hypothesis that
> $\sigma^2$ = 4.2 ppm against the alternative that $\sigma^2 \ne 4.2$
> ppm. Use a P -value in your conclusion.

Comment: It seems that the main question is how to find the P-value for a two-sided test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using the relationship
$$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1),$$
where $S^2$ is the variance of a sample of size $n=64$
from a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2,$
for your test of
$H_0:\sigma^2 = 4.2$
against
$H_a:\sigma^2\ne 4.2$
at the 5% level of significance.

The statistic $Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(63)$ has
$$P(42.95 < Q < 86.83) = 0.95,$$ so you reject $H_0$ at the 5%
level if $Q \le 42.95$ or $Q \ge 86.83.$ For your data
$Q = 63/75,$ which lies between the two critical values
$42.95$ and $86.83,$ so you do not reject $H_0.$ In R,

```
qchisq(c(.025,.975), 63)
[1] 42.95027 86.82959
```

In your problem the test statistic is
$$63S^2/4.2 = 63(4.25)/4.2 = 63.75$$
The probability of a more extreme result is the
probability in the right tail of $\mathsf{Chisq}(63)$
beyond $63.75,$ which is $0.45.$ This is the P-value
for a one-sided test (alternative $H_a: \sigma^2 > 4.2).$

It is [customary](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/12/12.1) to double that for a
two-sided test (alternative $H_a: \sigma^2 \ne 4.2),$ reporting P-value $0.90.$

```
1 - pchisq(63.75, 63)
[1] 0.4498938
```

---

*Notes:* (1) A second reference is [here](https://opentextbc.ca/introstatopenstax/chapter/test-of-a-single-variance/). See the P-value for the aquarium example, which is consistent with
doubling the P-value of a one-sided test to
get the P-value of a two-sided test.

```
pchisq(5.2094, 14)*2
[1] 0.03464066
```

(2) I do not find a test in the core of R for
a single variance. Here is output for
such a test from a recent version of Minitab (output edited for relevance).

```
Test for One Variance 

Method

Null hypothesis         σ-squared = 4.2
Alternative hypothesis  σ-squared ≠ 4.2

The chi-square method is only for the normal distribution.

Statistics

 N  StDev  Variance
64   2.06      4.25

                 Test
 Method      Statistic  DF  P-Value
 Chi-Square      63.75  63    0.900
```

Answer (score 0):

For a two tail test the p value has to be doubled. As the maximum value of p can be 1, we should take the value which after doubling will be less than 1. That is to say, right tail or left tail area depending upon the doubling being less than 1.

Comment: That's true of some tests, but the chi-square does not have a symmetric distribution, so it's not.